# How to change the directory during runtime?

Tags: python, file, directory, path

Let's assume I am writing Student details as a list into a CSV file.

Currently, I am working in a directory "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/Pythontraining".

But i want to store those CSV file in "StudentDetails" folder which is present in "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/StudentDetails" as well as

"/home/ubuntu/Documents/StudentDetails".I want to store the CSV file in both the directory during runtime. How should I do that?

```
try:
 os.chdir("/home/ubuntu/Desktop/StudentDetails")
 f=open(outfile, 'w')
 for j in m:
   writer = csv.writer(f)
   writer.writerow(j)
except OSError:
 print "Can't Change the current directory"
```

Comment: you don't have to change directory for that, just open the file with its absolute path

Comment: I am creating a new file (outfile). But i want to store it in a different directory.Say,I need to store the "outfile" into the folder whose name is "StudentDetails". In my case,I have created the "StudentDetails" folder in two different directory.I want to save the file(outfile) in both directory.How should i do it manually?